# How i can make button like this in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I can't understand how I can make this shape with short bottom angle:

[image]

I tried searching information about shapes and only found about rounded corners.

Comment: Hi @AmazingHorsess you can create the same button for that you need to use Box and create a layer using Image and Text as an overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CutCornerShape` like this:

```kotlin
Button(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    shape = CutCornerShape(
        topStart = 0f,
        topEnd = 0f,
        bottomEnd = 0f,
        bottomStart = 100f
    ),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.25f)),
    border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, Color.Green),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 64.dp)
) {
    Text(
        text = "Button",
        color = Color.Green
    )
}
```

The effect:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Find this solution:

```
@Composable
fun ButtonWithCutCornerShape() {

    Button(onClick = {}, shape = CutCornerShape(bottomStart = 50.dp)) {
        Text(text = "Cut corner shape")
    }
}
```